# Hokuyo LIDAR data on Graphical Interface

Tags: ros, lidar, hokuyo, stream, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have connected to Hokuyo UST -10LX lidar using ROS. I have installed the necessary wrapper and I could see that Lidar is working properly. When I do

*rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"* I am able to see a message

*Connected to network device with intensity and ID:xxxxxx*

*Streaming data*

I would now like to know how do I capture these data streams on the program to do further computation ?
Also, Is it possible to see the LIDAR data on any graphical interface?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236967/hokuyo-lidar-data-on-graphical-interface/) by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First thing you might need to check is the Topics , Are there any topics with the scan data ?

then Try running >rostopic list and find the "scan" topic
if it is exists, you can take it (the "scan" topic) into RVIZ app in order to visualize scan data (urg_node somehow had already create the frame of reference for you)

---

Originally posted by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) with karma: 150 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on 2016-06-15**:
Yes thank you, I can see 'scan' topic. But when I installed rviz on Ubuntu, I am getting segmentation fault. I'm not able to open the visualizer.  I am using ros Jade. What do you suggest me to do ?
I set the environment variable OGRE_RTT_MODE to Copy / FBO and checked, it was not helpful.

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-06-16**:
have you checked the Display Card Driver ? , i don't know exactly the solution but it might be the problem.